# Laravel 5.1: Auth::login() not persisting

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am using Laravel Socialite to authenticate user from Facebook. I am getting user data and able to store them in my database. But when I try to use Auth::check in my view it returns false. Though in Authenticate module it's returning true.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
use Auth;


class  Authenticate {

    /**
     * @var DbUserRepository
     */
    private $userRepo;
    /**
     * @var Socialite
     */
    private $socialite;
    /**
     * @var Guard
     */
    private $auth;


    /**
     * Constructor method for the class
     *
     * @param DbUserRepository $userRepo
     * @param Socialite $socialite
     * @param Guard $auth
     */
    function __construct(DbUserRepository $userRepo, Socialite $socialite, Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->userRepo = $userRepo;

        $this->socialite = $socialite;

        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Method to authenticate
     *
     * @param $driver
     * @param $hasCode
     * @param AuthenticateUserListener $listener
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function execute($driver, $hasCode, $listener)
    {   

        if( !$hasCode) return $this->getAuthorizationFirst($driver);

        $userData = $this->getSocialUser($driver);

        $user = $this->userRepo->findByEmailOrCreate($userData);

        $this->auth->login($user); 
        dd($this->auth->check()); //this returns true

        return $listener->redirectTo('/', $user);
    }


    /**
     * Authorization method if user does not have
     *
     * @param $driver
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function getAuthorizationFirst($driver)
    {
        return $this->socialite->driver($driver)->redirect();
    }


    /**
     * Method to register the user using the form
     *
     * @param $userData
     * @param AuthenticateUserListener $listener
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function registerUser($userData,AuthenticateUserListener $listener)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepo->findByEmailOrCreate($userData);

        $this->auth->login($user,true);

        return  $listener->redirectTo('/',null);
    }


    /**
     * Method to logout the user
     *
     * @param AuthenticateUserListener $listener
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function logoutUser(AuthenticateUserListener $listener)
    {
        $this->auth->logout();

        return $listener->redirectTo('/','');
    }


    /**
     * Method to retrive the user data after authorisation
     *
     * @param $driver
     * @return \Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\User
     */
    public function getSocialUser($driver)
    {
        return $this->socialite->driver($driver)->user();
    }

    public function checkUserIfExists($userData)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepo->findUserIfExists($userData);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

But in view:

`

```
<?php if(Auth::check()) { //**this returns false** ?>
    <div class="dropdown pull-right btn user-info user_profile_div">
      <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <img id="profile-pic" src="<?php echo url('img/saurabh.jpg') ?>"><span class="mobile-remove">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="user-name mobile-remove">Saurabh</span><span class="mobile-remove">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="profile_dropdown dropdown-menu profile_dropdown" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a href="<?php echo route('books.read') ?>">My Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo route('users.show') ?>">View Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo route('users.edit') ?>">Edit Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo route('pages.index') ?>">Sign Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

First of all you check ....token of user come on this page And Route

```
  // OAuth One Providers

  $token = $user->token;
  $tokenSecret = $user->tokenSecret;
```

After that you can check what is primary key in your databse and use the primary key like that..

```
protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
```

You can use this like that..

Extending Eloquent in BaseModel and then extening BaseModel in my user model. so was not able to Access any protected properties like primaryKey

I hope this is help you..this trick is working perfectly for me.....

Comment: Id is already my primary key in user model.
this solution not working :(